# How to fetch coefficients from ROM (actually BlockRAM in FPGA) to use in matrix multiplication?

Tags: conv-neural-network, matrix-multiplication, vivado, digital-design

We are senior year student who designs FPGA based Convolutional Neural Network accelerator.

We built pipelined architecture. (Convolution, Pooling, Convolution and Pooling), for this 4 stage of the architecture, we need to multiply one particular window and filter. We have (5*5)*6*16 window in the 2nd convolution layer and filter.

Up to here, I accept this is not a clear explanation. But the main problem in here is that we need to access 5*5*6*16 filter coefficients which are stored in block ram sequentially at the same time. But at every clock, I can just reach one particular address on the ROM.

What approach can we take?

Comment: You could try using a number of BRAMs that is an integer multiple of your window. Then you load the values into the window in a de-multiplexed fashion. If your FPGA has 100 BRAMs, for example, you could load the window in 24 clock cycles (5*5*6*16=2400; 2400/100 = 24). (i.e. BRAM 0-99 loads coefficients 0-99, then 100-199, 200-299, etc) You're correct in that you won't be able to load all 2400 coefficients in parallel in a single clock cycle.

Comment: There are a couple of big Xilinx devices you could buy a car for the price of a few. Static values can be composites provided by literals or generics, changing values at analysis time, elaboration time generics. Both requiring re-validation. FPGA synthesis doesn't support configuration declarations (Vivado has a max count of 10 for top level generics?). This sounds like a vendor tool issue, Xilinx likely wouldn't support a VHDL solution anyway. Too broad and not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

> What approach can we take?

You don't want to hear this but the only solution is:
Go back to the start and change your architecture/code. (or run very slowly)

You can NOT access 2400 coefficients sequentially unless you run the memory at a 2400 times the clock frequency of your main system. So lets say with a 100MHz RAM/ROM operating frequency your main system must run at ~42KHz.

This is a recurrent theme I encounter on these forums. You have made a wrong decision and now want a solution. Preferable an easy one. Sorry but there is none.

Comment: I got the point. Actually we implement first convolution with constant values (filter coeffs.) but in the second convolution layer the unforeseen problems appeared.

Now I am considering what you say about slowing all system, and reading at high freq. from ROM.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. For some layers we want to access multiple kernels for parallel operations, however, for a BRAM implementation you can have at most 2 accesses per cycle. So, the solution I made to this is to create a ROM array, whether implemented in BRAM style or Distributed style. 
Unlike RAM array, you can't just implement the ROM array as easily. So you need a script/software layer that generates RTL for your module.
I chose to implement with Distributed approach, however, I can't estimate the resources needed and the utilization reports give me unclear results. Still investigating into this.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference you could look into HLS pragmas to help use the FPGAs resources. What you could do is use the array partition pragma with the cyclic setting. This makes it so that each subsequent element of an array is stored in a different sub array.

For example with a factor of 4 there’d be four smaller arrays created from the original array. The first element in each sub array would be `arr[0]`, `arr[1]`, `arr[2]` respectively.

That’s how you would distribute an array across Block RAMs to have more parallel access at a time.